# Is it bad practice to have multiple DoWorkEventHandlers?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I have a Gui-Application that will perform different validations. As some of these validations might take longer I am running them in a BackgroundWorker, the current code looks like this:

```
//sample validator interface
public interface Validator
{
    void Validate();
}

//BGWs DoWork-method:

private void myBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ValidatorA.Validate();
    ValidatorB.Validate();
    ValidatorC.Validate();
}
```

Now there are some validators that have to support cancelation as well. This can be achieved by adding a pile of code or I can do it this way:

```
public interface Validator
{
    void DoValidationWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e);
}

class NormalValidator
{
    void DoValidationWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //validation-work
    }
}

class CancelableValidator
{
    void DoValidationWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bgw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        while(!bgw.CancellationPending)
        {
            //validation-work
        }
    }
}

//setup
myBGW.DoWork += ValidatorA.DoValidationWork;
myBGW.DoWork += CancelableValidatorB.DoValidationWork;
myBGW.DoWork += ValidatorC.DoValidationWork;
```

This will yield the same result according to my understanding, but every validator can handle cancelation on its own.

Is it okay to have multiple DoWork-Handlers or is this bad practice?

Comment: I don't know, but I'm not really convinced it will make the code simpler. While waiting for a better answer you can run code analysis on you project (with some quite strict rules like "Microsoft Extended Design Guideline Rules") and see what the guys at Microsoft think about it.

Answer (score 2):

You may find it cleaner to use inline anonymous functions for the majority of these. Eg:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (s, dwe) =>
{
    dwe.result = ...
    // do work here
};
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, rwe) =>
{
    if (rwe.Error != null) {
        // show dialog/message
    } else {
        var something = rwe.Result;
    }
};
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```